# How to read specific data from an object?

Tags: php, arrays, object

`{"TransactionInfo":{"Date":"06\/04\/2018","Time":"09:29 ET","TransactionCharge":{"MonetaryValue":"0.00","CurrencyCode":{}}},"ShipmentEstimate":{"CurrencyCode":"EUR","ShipmentCharges":{"TaxesAndFees":"1.7532","AdditionalInsuranceCost":"0.00","TransportationCost":"0.00","SubTotal":"1.7532"},"ProductsCharges":{"Product":{"TariffCode":"5109.90.80.00","Charges":{"Duties":"75.0021","TaxesAndFees":"0.00","VAT":"0.00","CostOfGoods":"1250.00","SubTotal":"1325.0021"}},"ProductsSubTotal":"1325.0021"},"TotalLandedCost":"1326.7553"},"SuppressQuestionIndicator":"Y"}`

How can I get only the value of TariffCode? 
Result must be: 5109.90.80.00

Comment: please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please json_encode that and repaste, that's unreadable

Comment: @delboy1978uk done

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$json = '{"TransactionInfo":{"Date":"06\/04\/2018","Time":"09:29 ET","TransactionCharge":{"MonetaryValue":"0.00","CurrencyCode":{}}},"ShipmentEstimate":{"CurrencyCode":"EUR","ShipmentCharges":{"TaxesAndFees":"1.7532","AdditionalInsuranceCost":"0.00","TransportationCost":"0.00","SubTotal":"1.7532"},"ProductsCharges":{"Product":{"TariffCode":"5109.90.80.00","Charges":{"Duties":"75.0021","TaxesAndFees":"0.00","VAT":"0.00","CostOfGoods":"1250.00","SubTotal":"1325.0021"}},"ProductsSubTotal":"1325.0021"},"TotalLandedCost":"1326.7553"},"SuppressQuestionIndicator":"Y"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);

echo $array['ShipmentEstimate']['ProductsCharges']['Product']['TariffCode'];
```

See it in action here: https://3v4l.org/2WBs6